# Zeroizing IBuffer?

Tags: c#, memory, encryption, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently building a Windows Store App that uses cryptography. This means extensive use of the `CryptographicBuffer` class. The app is very security-sensitive, so I would like to make sure to Zeroize any `Buffer`'s immediately after use. I am doing the same thing with `byte[]`'s when I use them.

To Zeroize them, currently we'd like to:

- Write all 1's.
- Write a pattern. Currently using 0,1,2,...254,255,0,1...
- Write all 0's.

The solution I have come up with is to create an extension method for each of `IBuffer` and `byte[]` which will do this for me. For `byte[]` I believe it's pretty straightforward:

```
public static void Zeroize(this byte[] bytes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
         bytes[i] = 255;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = (byte)(i % 255);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

For `IBuffer`, it's a little bit more difficult, in that you don't seem to get direct access to the `Buffer`. Through `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;` you do seem to get a few useful methods, such as `IBuffer.CopyTo` and `IBuffer.AsStream`, which give you direct access to the `Buffer` or underlying `Stream`. The solution I have come up with is this:

```
public static void Zeroize(this IBuffer buffer)
{
    var capacity = buffer.Capacity;
    byte[] toWrite = new byte[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        toWrite[i] = 255;
    }

    toWrite.AsBuffer().CopyTo(buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        toWrite[i] = (byte)(i % 255);
    }

    toWrite.AsBuffer().CopyTo(buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
            toWrite[i] = 0;
    }

    toWrite.AsBuffer().CopyTo(buffer);
}
```

My questions are thus: Is there a better way to be doing this? Is there any other hidden methods (`InteropServices` isn't really advertised all that well) that would make this a bit easier/more efficient/more secure?

Note: I realize the Zeroization process may be overkill, but it is requested by the Owner.

Comment: Without using direct memory pinning (ie. using the `unsafe` and `fixed` methods) can you be sure you're actually overwriting the right memory at all in a method you can't see? Performance wise, if the buffer is always a fixed size you could just create your zeroing arrays statically in advance and overwrite the memory blocks with them at the end rather than regenerating the same data in a loop each time.

Comment: Your first step currently is writing all 1s actually.

Comment: @owlstead: Ah, that's what I meant actually. Fixing in the post.

@Max: Unfortunately WinRT is unable to use `unsafe` methods. I'm not sure about `fixed` though. I think based on the doc, `Stream`s and `Buffer`s all access the same set of memory for their duration. With `Stream`s you also have to do `Seek`ing, `Flush`ing, etc. As to the fixed size of the buffer, that's a good idea! We've got a few standard sizes instances and a bunch of non-standard ones, so maybe making one for standard and one for non-standard would work well. I'll do some tests on the effects of that. Thanks for that idea!

Comment: @Max Ah, I see that `fixed` requires `unsafe`, so that is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: I ended up using unsafe methods to pin the memory as @Max mentioned, then did basically as I mentioned before. Though, it's been a long time since I asked this, so there may be a better way now.